# How to populate tableview controller with text input

Tags: ios, arrays, controller, nsmutablearray, tableview

I have created a table view controller with a `UITextField` on it. How can I populate the tableview controller cell of the input text that came from the `UITextField`. I tried the following but it seems the array is empty or being emptied

```
- (IBAction)endingInput:(id)sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];

    //send the message to the table cell
    NSMutableArray *history = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [history addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.chatMessageField.text]];
    [self.chatHistory addObject:history];
    [myTableView reloadData];

    //push the message to server
    [self initiateMessageSending:self.chatMessageField.text];

    chatMessageField.text = @"";
    [history release];
}
```

On my `cellForRowAtIndex` method;

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if(tableView == self.myTableView){
    cell.textLabel.text = [chatHistory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

I have set a break point but it doesn't pass there. I suspect my array is empty.

Likewise, where is the best place to call the `reloadData` method?

Also, `chatHistory` is private member, is there a way to initialize it like `[[self.chatHistory alloc] init];` ?

I know its a common question but I've been haggling with this for sometime now.

Comment: did you initialize chatHistory?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli - now I did, but still to no avail, I have NSLog my array and it shows that it has the encoded text input I made, what I can't do is to let the content of the array to display to the tableview cell

Comment: comment out the `if(tableView == self.myTableView){` and `}` and try

Comment: I think everyone's answers here added to the checks to solve the problem, but the funny thing, the culprit was the absence of delegate and datasource connection for the table... So always check for the connection before doing anything else. My apologies for the troubles and thanks for the prompt replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to alloc and init your `chatHistory`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.chatHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! And you should accept some guy's answer if you have solved your problem his/her answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't initializing `chatHistory` it doesn't even exist...never mind being empty!  (I'm not clear what "private member" means here.)

If you log the value of `chatHistory`, you'll see for sure whether it is nil or empty.

The other problem I see is that you're trying to load `chatHistory` with other (`history`) arrays but then use its content as a string.  You should decide whether it's going to be an array of arrays or an array of strings and then stay consistent.

(Also `[[self.chatHistory alloc] init];` isn't valid syntax for creating a new object.  Look at an [Objective-C language reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectAllocation/ObjectAllocation.html) for the right way.)